VisualStateManager in WPF
I inherited a WPF app written by vendors in VS2017. In an attempt to upgrade it to VS2022, an error message is thrown:

The object 'VisualStateGroup' already has a child and cannot add
'VisualState'. 'VisualStateGroup' can accept only one child.

This is the XAML that generates the error:
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition From="Normal" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3" To="MouseOver" />
                                    <VisualTransition From="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" To="Normal" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="SelectedUnfocused" />
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

Specifically the x:Name="MouseOver". Now I assume there is some tag missing to seperate the VisualState but for the life of me I cant figure it out. This code works fine in VS2019 thought.
Advise?
